# How to redirect a file to other file

Tags: bash, shell, pipeline

I've following two scripts:

```
A.sh 
B.sh
```

A.sh is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
some/path/ 2>/dev/null -jar some/path/java.jar "$1"
```

Let's assume that A.sh takes input as:

```
$ A.sh "some script"
```

And we'd redirect it to some output as:

```
$ A.sh "some script" > output.txt
```

And let's assume that B.sh takes a file *(file.txt)* as input and process it like:

```
$ B.sh "file.txt"
```

Now, I need a script which can pipeline output.txt to B.sh. Something which can perform below operations in a single script? (Is it possible to do so? If not, any solution?)

```
$ A.sh "some script" > output.txt
$ B.sh "output.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [*process substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
B.sh <(A.sh "some script")
```

`<(...)` is *process substitution*.  It makes the output of `A.sh` available to `B.sh` as a file-like object.  This works as long as `B.sh` does simple sequential reads.

This requires `bash` or other advanced shell.  *Process substitution* is not required by POSIX and, consequently, simple shells like dash do not support.

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> **Process Substitution**
>  Process  substitution  is supported on
>   systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of
>   naming open files.  It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The
>   process list is run with its input  or output  connected  to a FIFO or
>   some file in /dev/fd.  The name of this file is passed as an argument
>   to the current command as the result of the expansion.  If the >(list)
>   form is used, writing  to  the  file will provide input for list.  If
>   the <(list) form is used, the file passed as an argument should be
>   read to obtain the output of list.
>
> When available, process substitution is performed simultaneously with
>   parameter and variable  expansion, command substitution, and
>   arithmetic expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tee command in between the running of two commands to capture the output of the first command.

Example:-

```
   A.sh "some script" | tee output.txt | B.sh
```

The output for the A.sh script output is stored in the output.txt file and as well as it is passed to the input of the B.sh script.